# Copy a file to Shared Drive using Impersonate C#

Tags: c#, authentication, copy-paste, network-drive

I want to copy a file to a **Shared folder**. I can manually copy the file but I want to schedule it to run every hour.

First I made a batch file:

```
xcopy "D:\DATA\file.bak" "\\SharedFolder\DATA\"
```

It shows that the file has been copied, but there is nothing in the Shared folder.

Next I tried to use `File.Copy` but it didn't work as expected. I find that I need to have a **User Identity** for this.

So, here is my code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
IntPtr user = IntPtr.Zero;
bool loggedon = LogonUser(
"User", //Username
"Domain", //Domain
"", // Password
2, // interactive
0, // default
out user);
if (loggedon)
{
  using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(user))
  {
    File.Copy(Sourcepath, DestPath, true);
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
  }
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("Failed");
}
```

But this account doesn't have a password so I don't know what to put in the password field.

Is there another way to impersonate the current logged in user?
Or do I need to make a password?

Comment: This might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304398/is-it-possible-for-a-windows-service-impersonate-a-user-without-a-password

Comment: There's no need for impersonation or using passwords if you use eg Windows' Scheduled Tasks. You can specify that the job will run using a specific user's credentials.  Perhaps the question you should as is how to run your job using a specific user with whatever job scheduler you use?

Comment: @panagiotis_kanavos I did not know that Windows' Scheduled Tasks allow running program using specific user. That sound like exactly what I need.